# What should I do when a test specificity is zero?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, sensitivity-specificity

Upon doing a test that compares the effect of `imaging` versus regular tissue `biopsy` for cancer that has a prevalence of 90%, we found no true negative and we ended up with zero `specificity`. The cutoff for positivity in `imaging` was based on a prior publication, so I can't change that. The `2x2` contingency table (`confusion-matrix`) is shown below

I saw this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/527003/what-does-it-imply-when-the-sensitivity-1-000-and-specificity-0-000#:%7E:text=Specificity%20%3D0%20means%20you%20had,were%20incorrectly%20predicted%20as%20positive) and some quotations from it are shown below but it is not what I am looking for.

> Specificity =0; means you had some false positives and no true negatives: all actual non-cases were incorrectly predicted as positive. You might want to adjust your predictions so some are predicted positive and some negative. How you do this depends on how you are predicting.

- What adjustments do I need to make when I have extreme value in the confusion matrix as stated above i.e specificity = 0 e.g. is it correct to add 0.5 to some cells as we may do in meta-analysis in case of zero events?
- Is a specificity of 0 something acceptable although I intend to put the `2x2` table shown below?

Here is the confusion-matrix and results
[image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend that you consider your disease and the ability of imaging to detect it. Based on the sample, your imaging test reasonably excludes cancer, but there is insufficient data to comment on its ability to confirm the presence of cancer. My guess is that the sample is skewed toward patients with cancer and that the true prevalence of cancer is overestimated via your sampling method.